# How can I represent following series as a formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-writing, closed-form, combinatorial-proofs

(This is not an assignment question. It is part of my research, and while solving my case, I come with the following. This analytical thing proves with my simulation. But to write a paper, I need to formalize in generic equation/form)

I will present 3 examples first. Please note that the subtraction is between the first and last digit of any combination. Following is for all $n,k$ (provided $n>k$)

### Example 1: $\binom{n}{k} = \binom43 = 4$

So the combinations P is 
$$P = \{N_{123}, N_{124}, N_{134}, N_{234}\} = \{N_{3-1}, N_{4-1}, N_{4-1}, N_{4-2}\} = \{N_2,N_3,N_3,N_2\}$$

$$P = \{2N_2, 2N_3\}$$

### Example 2: $\binom{n}{k} = \binom53 = 10$

So the combinations P is 
$$P = \{N_{123}, N_{124}, N_{125}, N_{134}, N_{135}, N_{145}, N_{234}, N_{235}, N_{245}, N_{345}\} $$

$$P = \{N_{3-1}, N_{4-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{4-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{4-2}, N_{5-2}, N_{5-2}, N_{5-3}\} $$

$$P = \{N_{2}, N_{3}, N_{4}, N_{3}, N_{4}, N_{4}, N_{2}, N_{3}, N_{3}, N_{2}\} $$

$$P = \{3N_2, 4N_3, 3N_4\}$$

### Example 3: $\binom{n}{k} = \binom54 = 5$

So the combinations P is 
$$P = \{N_{1234}, N_{1235}, N_{1245}, N_{1345}, N_{2345}\} $$

$$P = \{N_{4-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{5-1}, N_{5-2} \} $$

$$P = \{N_{3}, N_{4}, N_{4}, N_{4}, N_{3}\} $$

$$P = \{2N_3, 3N_4\}$$

Comment: You can simply describe it in English (or a natural language).

Comment: If I understand what you are doing correctly the last line in example 2 should read $P = \{3N_2, 4N_3, 3N_4\}$  and example 3 should have $P = \{2N_3, 3N_4\} $

Comment: Yes you are right. My bad. I have made edits

Comment: A possible formalization of the question: Given $s$ a $k$-element subset of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$, define $\delta(s):= \max(s)-\min(s)$. Is there a formula to generate all pairs $(i,m)$ where $\delta(s)=i$ for some $s$, and where $m$ counts subsets $s$ with $\delta(s)=i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for a formula for the coefficient in front of $N_r$ in the output of your algorithm? Is so, the answer is
$$
(n-r)\binom{r-1}{k-2}.
$$
Proof is left as an exercise to the reader. (Hint: the $n-r$ factor accounts for choosing what the smallest element of the subset is).

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate, I am trying to work out the proof.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot find the proof....  ;( ;(. Can you be generous enough to provide the proof as well ^_^

Comment: Hint: The coefficient in front of $N_r$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose "width" is $r$, where the width of a subset is the difference between its largest and smallest elements. Such a subset can be chosen by first choosing what the smallest element $s$ is, which forces the largest element to be $s+r$, and then choosing what the remaining $\bf k-2$ elements in between are (note there is a "$r-1$ choose $\bf k-2$" in the formula...) How many ways are there to choose $s$? $s$ must be at least $1$, but cannot be too big since you need $s+r\le n$. @Kashan